# How do I load the CSS of the page when displaying offline WebView using local html?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want a WebView component to display both when online and offline. When online, I want it to use the url I have provided. I want it automatically locally saved/Cached so it can also be displayed when offline. But the problem is that the offline version of the webview only displays the minimal text-only version of the page. Here's a code I used:

```
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function App() {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true);
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check network status
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      setIsOnline(state.isConnected);
    });

    // Load or fetch HTML content
    loadHtmlContent();

    // Clean up the subscription when the component unmounts
    return () => {
       unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const loadHtmlContent = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if HTML content is already stored
      const storedHtml = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myHtmlContent');

      if (storedHtml) {
        setHtmlContent(storedHtml);
      } else {
        // Fetch live content (e.g., from an API)
        const liveHtml = await fetch('https://wikipedia.org');
        const liveHtmlText = await liveHtml.text();

        // Store the live HTML content
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('myHtmlContent', liveHtmlText);
        setHtmlContent(liveHtmlText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error loading HTML content:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isOnline ? (
        <WebView
          style={styles.webview}
          source={{ uri: 'https://wikipedia.org' }}
        />
      ) : (
        <WebView
          style={styles.webview}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{ html: htmlContent }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});`
```

I tried searching online for help but to no avail. I'm pretty new at React-Native so Please keep it simple when explaining in the replies.